# vincenty distance in series

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with columns latitude and longitude, and want to calculate vincenty distance between two consecutive points `pi` and `pi+1`.

```
         lat           long  
1    39.9852833333333  116.307367  
2    39.9852166666667  116.309550  
3    39.9851333333333  116.309767  
4    39.9850666666667  116.309883  
5    39.9847333333333  116.309933  

df['distance'] = vincenty( (df['lat'],df['long']), (df['lat'].shift(-1), df['long'].shift(-1)) )
```

I'm getting following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need create new columns first and then use `dropna` for remove last `NaN`s rows in `lat_shifted` and `long_shifted`, so last value of `Vincenty_distance` is `NaN`:

```
df['lat_shifted'] = df['lat'].shift(-1)
df['long_shifted'] = df['long'].shift(-1)

df['Vincenty_distance'] = df.dropna().apply(lambda x: vincenty((x['lat'], x['long']), (x['lat_shifted'], x['long_shifted'])), axis = 1)
```